# Repeating linear background displayed incorrectly

Tags: css, google-chrome, html-table

I recently discovered a strange displaying issue in Chrome while trying to place a repeating gradient on a table row:

**[see the Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4nb9B/2/)**

```
<table id="one">
    <tr><td>123</td><td>asd</td><td>brgfbb</td><td>sdf</td><td>bgfb</td></tr>
</table>

#one tr{
   background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(135deg, 
                     #bada55, #bada55 5px, 
                     transparent 5px, transparent 10px);
}
```

Placing such a gradient on the `td` element of course won't work. However,
when placing the gradient on the `tr` the gradient strangely is disrupted as if it was placed on the `td`s. The breaks are exactly where the table cells touch. When placing the gradient on the table instead, the stripes have irregular size.

Chrome:

[image: Chrome linear gradient bug]

In Firefox everything looks nice:

[image: Firefox gradient]

P.S. IE10 has the same problems with the gradient on the `tr`, directly on the table element everything looks fine.

Do you know any workarounds for this issue?

Comment: I'd really like to know the reason for the downvote... ;)

Comment: Could you set a quick fiddle up?

Comment: @SpaceBeers I have the feeling, you did not read beyond the first sentence of my question... guess why;) I edited my answer to make the fiddle even more prominent.

Comment: Guilty. Totally skimmed it till the code. I am totally stumped.

Answer (score 0):

This can be fixed by just applying the css to the id you are using - #one or #two. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/83shD/) here demonstrating -- you can see that I changed it from

```
#one tr{
    background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(135deg, #bada55, #bada55 5px, transparent 5px, transparent 10px);
    padding:0;margin:0;
}
```

to

```
#one {
    background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(135deg, #bada55, #bada55 5px, transparent 5px, transparent 10px);
    padding:0;margin:0;
}
```

And no more disrupted background image :)

Comment: Thank you for looking into this. However your solution is exactly what I referred to in my question: `When placing the gradient on the table instead [...]` which you can see in my reference table `#two`. This also changes the semantic of the selector significantly, which cannot always be done. Also, the stripes still have irregular size in that case. And last but not least, your fiddle matches mine exactly...